# Is it Haram to have a golden iPhone or halal

Tags: sin

I have a golden iPhone 8 and I am worried then I am sinning because I am putting it in my pocket is this halal or haram?

Comment: Are you speaking about the gold color iPhone??

Comment: I am talking about the gold iPhone yes :)